# How to calculate the dot product of two lists without importing modules?

Tags: python, math

I have this task to do the dot product of two vectors in the form of lists. I tried this method but it gives me the wrong answer, not quite sure what the issue is.

```
def scalar_product(vec1,vec2):
    new_list = []
    a_zip = zip(vec1, vec2)
    result = 1
    zipped_list = list(a_zip)
    for lists in zipped_list:
        for integer in lists:
            result = result * integer
            new_list.append(result)
    return sum(new_list)

print(scalar_product([1,1,1],[2,2,2]))
```

So my thought process here was to first `zip` the lists together so I get one big list containing sublists. Then I looped through the lists and the sublist to multiply the values in the sub-lists and append that to a `new_list`. And then to sum up the `new_list`. But the output here is 21 when it actually should be 6.

I don't want to `import` any modules or such for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
def scalar_product(vec1,vec2):
  total_sum = 0
  for x, y in zip(vec1, vec2):
    total_sum = total_sum + (x*y)
  return total_sum
```

```py
print(scalar_product([1,1,1],[2,2,2]))
# 6
```

Here is what each step is doing.
Take the example: `vec1 = [1,2,3]`, `vec2=[5,6,7]`

```
zip(vec1,vec2) # is an iterator with value [(1,5),(2,6),(3,7)]
total_sum = 0 # the total sum is currently initialized to zero.
for x,y in zip(vec1,vec2) # assigns x and y from the zipped iterator.
# On the first round x = 1, y = 5
# On the second round x = 2, y = 6
# On the final round x = 3, y = 7
  total_sum = total_sum + (x*y)
# On the first round total_sum = 0 + 1*5 = 5
# On the second round total_sum = 5 + 2*6 = 17
# On the final round total_sum = 17 + 3*7 = 38
  return tota_sum # total_sum is now 38.
```

Comment: This isn't the scalar product. You still have to sum the elements of the list.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this one liner

```
a,b= [1,1,1],[2,2,2]
c= sum([(lambda x,y: x*y)(x,y)for x,y in zip(a,b)])
```

Comment: `(lambda x,y: x*y)(x,y)` is a pretty roundabout way of writing `x*y`. Also, you can sum over the generator expression directly (which avoids storing an intermediary list) by getting rid of the square brackets `[`, `]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
def scalar_product(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(map(lambda x, y: x*y, vec1, vec2))
```

A trivial import from the standard library makes this simpler:

```
from operator import mul

def scalar_product(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(map(mul, vec1, vec2))
```

If you are really averse to an import, and you know the type of value in the vectors, you can hard-code an unbound method instead. (But really, just use the trivial import.) For example,

```
def scalar_product(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(map(float.__mul__, vec1, vec2))
```

You can also use a generator expression in place of `map`:

```
def scalar_product(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(x*y for x, y in zip(vec1, vec2))
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make obtain the answer, one that is easy to read is as follows: (it iterates number of times equal to the length of the vectors and sum the multiplications)

```
def scalar_product(vec1,vec2):
    sum=0
    for count in range(0,len(vec1)): # could be len(vec2), it doesn't matter
        sum=sum+vec1[count]*vec2[count]
    return sum
print(scalar_product([1,1,1],[2,2,2]))
```